# NLP Классификация документов

Tags: python, nlp

Есть набор документов - контракты, акты, служебки и т.д.
Необходимо в последующем проверять соответствие нового документа одному из классов (контракт? акт? и т.д.)
В каком направлении идти? Может быть есть алгоритм такого анализа? Какими библиотеками пользоваться? Пока набрел на Gensim.

Comment: Обычная задача классификации https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification

Comment: Самое сложное в этой задаче это получить __качественную__ обучающую выборку. Т.е. большой (желательно 10.000+) набор документов для каждого из которого известен результат -  контракт, акт, служебка и т.д. После этого задача решается и на этом сайте есть достаточно примеров ее решения ;)

Comment: Если по некоторым словам можно точно определить тип документа, то можно создать набор правил и прогонять документы через него. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что это не ваш случай

Comment: MaxU, спасибо за ответ! Вы так же ответили:"и на этом сайте есть достаточно примеров ее решения ;) – MaxU 8 часов назад" К сожалению даже не знаю где искать :))) А так пробую подставлять ключевые слова. Вроде получается понемногу. Просто хотел поглядеть в сторону "взрослых" алгоритмов.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала стоит определиться с предобработкой документов. То есть, в каком виде требуется представить исходный документ. Это может быть вектор с частотами слов в документе (bag-of-words), а может быть сумма из векторов слов `word2vec`. В обоих случаях подойдёт библиотека `gensim`. Bag-of-words можно создать как обычный, так и с TF-IDF частотами для каждого слова. Также можно найти примеры использования своеобразного гибрида bag-of-words с word2vec подходом (вектор слова просто домножается на IDF слова)

Просле предобработки документов уже можно подумать о классификаторе. Он может быть как и простой (разнообразие таких можно найти в библиотеке `sklearn`), так и нейронный (`keras, tensorflow, pytorch`). Если рассматривать простой классификатор, то легче всего начать с решающего дерева, который рассматривает bag-of-words как набор правил и делает вывод по каждому документу.